# Detect when a user comes through the new Facebook Authenticated Referrals

Tags: facebook

With the new Authenticated Referrals in the new FB auth system, the user logs in before even hitting my app.

My question is, is there any way to detect when a user has just come from one of these authenticated referrel dialogs? For example, by specifying the redirect_uri on them and appending some GET params.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/summary you can set the domain and the website of your application.

Facebook, for security reason will only redirect to the website you set here passing you some parameters in the HTTP GET url (for example the access token just generated for that user), to decide which of these parameter you want to receive you have to go to settings -> auth dialog then at the bottom of the page Authenticated Referrals -> Auth Token Parameter.

EDIT:
If you want to be sure that an user just used the auth dialog you can use a simple workaround:  read the access token from the url, then check if this is the 1st time you see this token, if so you can test the validity of the token by performing a simple operation that the particular user accepted you (or better your facebook app) can do with his profile.. The easiest way is probably to send a request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=...
```

If token is valid then it IS reliable.

Comment: I was thinking about detecting for the presence of the &code= parameter or the #access_token fragment to detect when a user has just authorized my app. However, this doesn't seem to work (maybe its because its a canvas app?) and the only thing that gets appended is "#_=_".

My second question is, are the 2 aforementioned parameters a reliable indicator?

Comment: Mine is a Canvas app too, however in the section "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" I put my web site, which in my case, is a simple server hosted in Google App Engine which elaborates the access token I receive from the auth dialog.
And for your 2nd question, what do you mean by reliable?

Comment: I've set all that stuff. But Facebook does not append an access_token or code value to the url. It redriects to my app with a URL like: http://apps.facebook.com/myapp#_=_

Comment: The problem with this method is that you would need to check to see if the user is in the database on every page load of every page just to catch the 0.001% of page requests that come from an authenticated referral. As far as I see there is no way to do this in an app. Facebook does append ?code=... for websites that use Facebook authenticated referrals. I don't see why they can't do something similar for a canvas app.

Comment: In my personal humble opinion, suggesting an alternative, would be a nice thing after downvoting a question. Not just "I don't like your answer even if I see no alternative"

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this problem myself. It would have been a lot better if Facebook just passed auth_ref=true or something. Anyway, I came up with a system that seems to work for me using cookies.

I already have a page that I use as the redirect url for the fb auth dilaog. This page initializes the user and sets a cookie. If that cookie is not present and the signed request has a token, then I redirect to this page. I can't tell if the user either came from an authenticated referral or some other path like a bookmark, but it doesn't matter for my purposes.

You can see the details at:
http://developsocialapps.com/authenticated-referrals-facebook-apps/

Basically something like this:

```
// on somepage.php
if (signed request has token && url is not redirect page && user doesn't have cookie) {
    redirect to redirect.php;
}

// on redirect.php
set cookie;
redirect back to somepage.php
```